# Max watt bulb for an old "660w 250v" table lamp?

Tags: watts, lamp

I have an old table lamp that's imprinted "LEVITON / MADE IN USA / 660W 250V / LAMP HOLDER".

I'm used to lamps with stickers that specifically tell me what max-watt bulbs I can use, usually 60W, 75W, or 100W.

Why is this lamp printed "660W", and what's its actually safe, maximum-wattage bulb?

Photos below. There's a UL sticker, but otherwise nothing else is printed or stuck on the lamp sides or bottom.

[image: photo]  [image: photo]

Comment: How big was the table?!

Comment: The table lamp measures less than 12 inches in height without its shade.

Comment: @Transistor Maybe it's a table lamp meant for the darkest of nights. Like during the heat death of the universe.

Comment: It's likely that you're looking at a 'generic' bulb holder, made by Leviton, and that the bulb holder by itself is rated for up to 660W. That carries no weight when you want to know what the fixture as a whole is rated for.

Comment: So if practically nothing else is printed anywhere on the lamp, there's no way to know its maximum wattage? I'll add photo above now.

Comment: 660W is more of a searchlight than a table lamp.

Comment: Maybe we can approach this from a different angle. What kind of lamp are you intending to put in the socket? If you are planning to use a fluorescent or LED lamp then I don't think you need to worry about wattage limits. If you are planning to use an incandescent of 60W or less, I am sure that is OK, just based on past experience with table lamps.

Comment: Just looking to replace bulbs around the house. I prefer halogens, but apparently they're being phased out for [shudder] LEDs.

Comment: Halogen is a type of incandescent. I am sure it is OK to use 60W or lower halogens if you have them. If you go to LED or fluorescent then you probably don't need to worry about it since those are generally 20W or less actual power consumption.

Comment: I don't mind the better LED lamps. I have been happy with the color temperature and life and they don't flicker. Some hum when they are on dimmers. But I did have to shop around before I found the LED's that seem to last.

Comment: 660 watt may melt socket and burn shadow. Street light fixtures have less power.

Comment: 660 watt may melt socket and burn shadow. Street light fixtures have less power. It may be 60 watt, but for table lamp 40 watt is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Without any other information, you are left with trial and error. With an incanddescent bulb you need to be concerned about overheating the shade. With an LED bulb the concern would be the temperature of the control circuit in the bulb.

The 660 watt rating of the lamp holder would indicate that should never be a concern, other parts of the lamp will always be the limiting factors.

Unless the shade is ridiculously small, I would think a 60 W incandescent would be fine and 100 W probably ok. For 150 W, you should probably have a larger clearance between the bulb and shade than would be usual for a single-bulb lamp. The safety issue comes down to the possibility of the shade catching fire, but you might also want to avoid discoloration.

Comment: Seems like 660W 250V is the standard rating for many UL-listed sockets, including [silly](https://www.rona.ca/en/keyless-ceiling-lampholder-660w-250v-04805495?viewStore=55070&&cm_mmc=shopping_google-_-8143180960-_-88023293927-_-pla-855994253037&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIs7mYs5Wv6QIVAeiGCh3yZACHEAYYASABEgL_tPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) plastic ones. Modern lamps have a fixture rating sticker (looked at two and one was 40W and the other 150W- and of course if you change the shade the rating might be different). With LED or CF lamps, nothing will be a worry, of course.

Comment: Trial and error? But I want a little sticker (or anonymous stranger online) to promise guaranteed safety! Thank you for your feedback (upvoted).

Comment: I would not say that there is nothing to worry about with LED of CF, but since the photo seems to show no blockage of air flowing upward from below and no indication that the bulb will be enclosed, there would likely be nothing to worry about. However it has been my experience that LEDs and CFs are very sensitive to blockage of air flow.

Answer (score 1):

If the socket faces up like that (bulb goes in base down), then the 660W limit has only to do with heat that might transmit down to the socket. You can use anything UP TO 660W, which for a table lamp would be ridiculous. Anything less than 660W is fine.

Comment: Your summation of the orientation is correct. Thank you for your feedback (upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

The 660W rating you see is the rating **of the socket component** of the lamp.  Note that actual 660W lamps with Edison bases are basically unheard of.

The lamp fixture (luminaire) will have its own rating.  For that you must consult its labeling and/or instructions, which are part of its UL Listing.

Search the luminaire, including the base, for anything about that.

Otherwise, 60W is a very safe assumption.  And that is more than you'll ever want in the 21st century since CFLs came and went and LED is king... 60 *actual* watts of LED would be an insane amount of light.

The watt ratings of luminaires are thermal; they are the max that the lamp is certified for to not start a fire.  As such, it is relevant to the heat output, not the light output.